A lightning bolt strikes the White House. How much power would it require so that its exuded energy can ignite the entire landmass of the USA?
I have a Lightning Deity in the Gulf of Mexico that wants to intimidate modern Earth and decides to throw a lightning bolt at the White House. As the lightning strikes the White House, the heat, light, and sheer energy it produces should cause everything in its general vicinity and the USA to burst into flames. It hopes that the visual impact and the seeming destruction of the most powerful nation in the world under its hands would terrify the world into submission.
The lightning strike is directed and concentrated so it won't harmlessly disperse. Now, it only needs to calculate how much power the lightning bolt needs to achieve the result it wants.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

A single lightning bolt to get the entire country, yet aimed at the White House (which is definitely not centrally located)?  Including Alaska and Hawaii, presumably as part of the USA, but not Canada, which is between Alaska?  That "isn't intended to demolish" but "would cause everything within the USA to burst into flames"?  The last requirement alone is contradictory - please consider what you want the exact effect to be and update the question, noting that it is outright impossible for a single lightning bolt to target the entire USA and only the USA.

Why would an actual god with no apparent constraints on its power need to worry about puny mortal concerns like voltages?

Volts alone can't ignite anything. They need amperes.

@AlexP depends what you're igniting. Not much current in a piezoelectric gas lighter, for example. And if you're prepared to apply all the volts, things get Really Interesting once you reach the Schwinger limit...

Why would you need to calculate the power output for that? It seems quite literally irrelevant

Even if they restricted themselves to the 48 contiguous states, they'd be wiping out most of Canada, all of Mexico, and much of South America, with the Gulf of Mexico itself being close to the center of the destruction. Apart from the global effects strongly resembling an impact by a dinosaur-killing asteroid, why would they destroy their own home? And presumably their own followers who lived there?

I think there is no such lightning.

Does this "Lightning Deity in the Gulf of Mexico" have an origin story connected to the K-Pg event?

Xkcd What If had a recent YT video about this.

"should cause everything in (the White House's) general vicinity and the USA to burst into flames". (1) Look at a map.  (2) Sand can't catch fire.

What if all lighnigh in the world hits the same place: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fs28lEq9smw

According to Science, this can't be done
Lightning is a point solution not dissimilar to a laser beam in this context. Moving heat from one geographic location to another takes time. In the mean time, the original target location is getting hotter and hotter. A single lightning strike, if all it did was create heat, would create a kilometers-deep puddle of liquid glass by the time California burst into flames.
Worse, if you dumped all the energy into the bolt at once (which lightning is prone to do) and it was enough to burn California, it would cause an explosion in Washington D.C. that would put the Chicxulub crater to shame.
The only solution that will achieve the goal you've stated is to rain lightning across the United States simultaneously, causing small localized damage, but resulting in everything burning. That, at least, would permit my suspension of disbelief.
Note that the heat would expand spherically. it would max out at the exosphere, but it would travel otherwise in a circle out from Washington D.C. In other words, to hit D.C. and burn California would also burn most of the Atlantic Ocean, most of Canada, Cuba, chunks of Central and South America.... If you want to limit it to principally the U.S., the lightning needs to hit at Lebanon, Kansas. (Source)
Finally, it's not voltage you need to worry about. It's power. Voltage multiplied by Current equals power in watts. A million-volt lightning strike with a microamp of current is just one watt (compared to your hair dryer that uses 1500 watts). And to burn rather than destroy it would need to be a very low voltage with an enormous current resulting in the proverbial one-point-twenty-one gigawatts (and likely a lot more than that).
Most of the time energy is measured in joules. The 50 megaton Tsar Bomba, the largest nuclear test detonation in history, had a 22 mile 100% destruction blast radius using 210 peta-joules. You'd need to drop hundreds of Tsar Bombas across the U.S. to make everything burn. It's an excessive answer, but it's designed to give you the scope of your problem. Let's say we need only 10% of the damage in that 22 mile radius. Cheating horrifically, that's 21 peta-joules... hundreds of times. Rain lightning everywhere. That's the ticket.

12 petatons of explosive.
https://nuclearweaponsedproj.mit.edu/fireball-size-effects
I did a quick calculation there and to reliably get fire to hit all the land of the USA, Hawaii included, you need an energy strike around 100 times more powerful than the asteroid that caused the extinction of the dinosaurs. This will likely cause the end of all life on the planet, with only a few astronauts surviving for a short period longer.
The few astronauts remaining would no doubt be very intimidated, and very confused.

Exploding isnt really an option (per the other answers), but that does not mean the plot ends there.
If he is the lightning deity, you only need to bent a very small amount to 'controls electricity'. The deity could basically fry everything connected to a wire. The deity could make a damn explode, or make every lightbulb blast into parts, or turn of all traffic lights (or all of the above), it would already be enough to cripple a country. Just imagine: No working coffee machines!
Currently the world is working on hardening sewege and power and internet and water supplies and other basic infrastructure from hackers because if they get access to one of those they can wreak havoc. But all those things need power, so you can massively overload them, having havoc that way.
If it where to explode the devices in 1 big dam as a warning, all other parties would become very careful what happens next, as the whole world basically depends on power, to disconnecting everything is not an option al all.
